# How to manage @synthesize for iOS5 and iOS6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

I am working on an app and have to support for `iOS5` and `iOS6`. We don't need to write `@synthesize` in `iOS6`. I am writing `@synthesize` for `iOS5`. But read that writing `@synthesize` increases compile time.

Is there any alternative for this? If remove it, what does it will affect. What if I submit to iTunes without writing `@synthesize`?

Comment: "writing @synthesize increases compile time." If it does, it's probably on the order of milliseconds. I can't imagine someone so impatient as to want to fix this "extra delay" :-)

Comment: Is it such a big deal to increase compile time?  Comments increase compile time too -- do you omit those for that reason?

Comment: Any way you will submit to iTunes app compiled with IOS7 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

> With Xcode 4.4 and LLVM Compiler 4.0 the @synthesize directive is no longer required as it will be provided by default. That means in most cases you now only need the @property and the compiler takes care of everything else for you.

@synthesize is not related with iOS version, is a new feather of Xcode and LLVM Compiler.